# How to get raw unwritten querystring

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting

Without permalink enabled, the urls look like ?p=1 and when permalink is activated it's the postname that appears... question .. isn't this a rewritten version of ?p=1 ..

When I use $_GET['p'], there is nothing in there... is that normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_GET` refers literally to `?p=1` part of URL. With pretty permalink if it's empty then there is nothing to access.

WordPress processed either case into query variables of `WP_Query` class. You should use [`get_query_var()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_query_var/) to retrieve things like this, so in this specific case it would probably be `get_query_var( 'p' )`.

Comment: but there is actually a rewrite being made right? is wp emptying the $_GET? is there a way to get the original untouched $_GET?

Comment: @yeahman if your URL doesn't have `?something=whatever` part then there is no `$_GET`. Rewrite process doesn't make it appear.

Comment: normally for most rewrite, you still can access the $_GET even if it is not visible in your url. I am not sure how WP is doing the rewrite though... maybe a different way?

Comment: looking at the code, yup rewriting is done differently in wp...